# RDS restart event sends two emails using SNS and Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, rds

I have configured RDS restart event with AWS Lambda and added trigger as SNS.Whenever RDS gets restarted it sends two emails.Can it be limited to one email rather than two emails.
Any help\suggestion on this will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying the two messages are *precisely* identical?

Comment: Er, why not turn off one of those triggers?

Comment: I have configured one SNS topic for RDS restart event but I am getting two emails.